# Three.js grid Axis label issue and how to plot x,y,z data on the grid

Tags: javascript, plot, three.js, grid, label

I am supposed to plot the well deviation surveys on a 3D grid. With the help of a few articles on the web, I have accomplished a 3D grid with required size. The current problem I am facing right now is that the labels for x,y and z axis are attached to the grid, rather they are misplaced on the scene.

```
var labelsH = labelAxis(height, data.labels.y,"y");
        labelsH.position.x = width;
        labelsH.position.y = - height +(2*height/a)-20;
        labelsH.position.z = depth;
        scene.add(labelsH);

function labelAxis(width, data, direction){

  var separator = 2*width/data.length,
            p = {
                x:0,
                y:0,
                z:0
            },
            dobj = new THREE.Object3D();

  for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++ ) {
        var label = makeTextSprite(data[i]);

        label.position.set(p.x,p.y,p.z);

        dobj.add( label );
        if (direction=="y"){
            p[direction]+=separator;
        }else{
            p[direction]-=separator;
        }
    //console.log(p.x+":"+p.y+":"+p.z)
  }
  return dobj;
}
```

See the https://jsfiddle.net/3tw3dt1u/ for full code example.

Further more, the data that I need to plot is already in the jsFiddle mentioned above. Having minimal javascript skills, I have no idea how this data will be plotted on the grid to form something like this:

[see image for required result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUfZ6.png)

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is regarding the plotting of the points, this is how it could be done:

[JSFiddle working example](https://jsfiddle.net/3tw3dt1u/3/)

The key points are below.

```
// Not necessary, but I prefer to use the same scale as they use in their example. It's also easier since the data is according to those scales.
var graphDimensions = {
    w:3000,
    d:3000,
    h:7000
};


var vectors = realData.map(function(d) { // Create vectors from your data
    return new THREE.Vector3(d[0], d[1], d[2]);
});

var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(vectors); // Create a curve with the vectors created above

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: "blue"}); // Material for the curve

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var splinePoints = curve.getPoints(5000); // The 5000 in here is the resolution (number of points) on the curve. Increase for a smoother curve, decrease for a more jagged curve.

for (var i = 0; i < splinePoints.length; i++) { // Loop through the points to create vertices in the geometry
  geometry.vertices.push(splinePoints[i]);
}

var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material); // Create a line with your geometry and material
scene.add(line); // Add it to the scene

line.rotateX(Math.PI / 2); // Orient the line correctly
boundingGrid.position.set(0, -3.5, 1.5); // Move the grid into position
boundingGrid.scale.set(0.001, 0.001, 0.001); // Reduce by whatever scale you want to decrease it in size (otherwise you have to scroll out forever)
line.scale.set(0.001, 0.001, 0.001);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot simnys. Apprciate it. I have made some adjustments in boundingGrid.position and scale to bring the grid into the center of the page and scaled it a little smaller. But as you can see in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3tw3dt1u/4/ that the line doesn't move with the grind position and scaling changes. What do I do to attache the line with the Grid, so that it should move with the grid position changes?

Comment: Also, I was trying to put labels around the x,y and z axis of the Grid. For that purpose I have added some code but the Labels are not attached with the grid either. I need to display the data.labels.x,y,z on the grid as demonstrated in the image file attached to the original question. Hope, you might shed some light on that as well. Thanks.

Comment: Moreover, the data would be coming from database, so each time the scale might be different. Do I need to change the graphDimensions accordingly each time? And does this curve.getPoints(5000) has to do with the data to be plotted or 5000 would work for any kind of data ranges?

Comment: It's easiest if you make sure the gridDimensions adhere to the data that you are receiving, say the max value for height you get is 7000, then it makes sense to use that, since your datapoints will exist in relation to that 7000. getPoints(5000) should work for anything, it's just how many pieces the curve will be split into.

Comment: About the labels, I don't have time to fix that at the moment, but they are there in the scene they are just misplaced, you need to place them in relation to the position of your boundingGrid.

Comment: Also, since there are negative values in the realData you have to account for that when you make your bounding grid, if you use your JSFiddle and do this:

`line.position.set(0, 1, -0.5);`
the line will be aligned with the grid

Comment: After a lot of struggle, hit and try I couldn't place the labels on the right position and make them rotate with the grid. :(